# How can I use a custom font in Scratch using CSS and @font-face?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

How do I make a custom font from scratch?

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: JuneBug;
    src: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/grannygamer777/DerpFont/main/my%20derp%20handwriting.ttf');
}

h1 {
    font-family: JuneBug
}
```

```html
<textarea
    class="paint-editor_text-area_27Ci4"
    spellcheck="false"
    style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 40px; line-height: 1.2; display: initial; transform-origin: 0px 36px; transform: matrix(0.5, 0, 0, 0.5, 48.35, 59.25); width: 256.645px; height: 48px;"
></textarea>
```

i dont know how to merge the codes together

Comment: I could not understand the question. Can you explain better?

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you must fix for your code to work:

1. You applied the style only to `h1`, not to `textarea`. I suggest you add the `textarea selector like so:

```css
h1, textarea {
    font-family: JuneBug
}
```

2. In the `textarea`'s `style` attribute, you already have set the font to Arial. Remove the `font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;` part of the `style` attribute, else the custom font will not show.

Comment: @epiccoderorsomethingidkman: besides you should specify a font-weight since headings like `<h1>` use font-weight:bold/700 by default: `@font-face {
    font-family: JuneBug;
    src: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/grannygamer777/DerpFont/main/my%20derp%20handwriting.ttf');
  font-weight:400;
}`. Otherwise your font  is artificially "boldened".

Comment: i mean merging the code together

Answer (score 1):

Hi just like any other css selector:
In your css file or style tag :

```
textarea {
    font-family: JuneBug;
}
```